# How to query latest documents from the mongoose schemas and

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I designed my mongoose Schema as

## Schemas

#### User Schema

```
{
  first_name: {type: String, required: true},
  last_name: {type: String},
  email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
  password: {type: String, required: true},
  isVerified: {type: Boolean, required: false},
  dob: {type: Date},
  from: {
    city: {type: String},
    state: {type: String}
  },
  gender: {type: String},
  phone_no: {type: Number},
  cover_pic: {type: String},
  profile_pic: {type: String},
  about:{type: String},
  social:{
    instagram:{type: String},
    facebook:{type: String},
    youtube:{type: String},
    twitter:{type: String}
  }
},{
  timestamps: true
}
```

#### Location Schema

```
Location:{
name : { type: String, required: true },
  address : {
    street: { type: String, required: true },
    area: { type: String, required: true },
    city: { type: String, required: true },
    zip_code: { type: Number, required: true },
    state: { type: String, required: true }
  },
  description : { type: String, required: true },
  lat : { type: Number, required: true },
  long : { type: Number, required: true },
  phone_number : { type: Number, required: true },
  facilities : [{type: String}],
  location_type : { type: String, required: true },
  location_website : { type: String, required: true },
  //Reviews//
  reviews : [{
    rating: { type: Number, required: true },
    review : { type: String, required: true },
    reviewed_by: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' ,required: true, }
  }],
  //Post//
  post: [{
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    location: { type: String, required: true },
    imagesPaths: [String],
    videosPaths: [String],
    creatorId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' ,required: true, }
  }]
}
```

You can see I have embedded Post and Review documents in the Location Document.

#### Requirement

A `User` can add **single** `Review` and **multiple** `Post` for a specific `Location` in this way there would be many locations.

---

### Question

I want to query 
**Queries**
 1. Latest `Reviews` as well as Latest `Post` from all the `Locations`
 2. Reviews and Posts of a Specific User

Is this the proper approach of the **schema** creation according to my requirement. Or should I use reference for the relationships and also tell how do I perform those two queries using mongoose.

Comment: Hey mate, i would split the schemas even further. One schema with users, one with locations, one with reviews and one with posts. I would also add timestamps to reviews and posts with https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps. This way you can query against locations and populate it with only the latest review and post with the help of sort and slice functionality. The same goes for users. You should save the user reference on Location, Review and Post-schemas and then use mongoose virtuals (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html) on the User schema for your 2nd question.

Comment: You should also add compound unique indexes (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes) for the Review Schema on location and user. This way one user will not be able to post more than 1 review for the same location.

Comment: @JonathanNielsen I read many articles which suggest me to use embedded documents because reference documents decreases performance and it takes more time to execute queries

Comment: That is true in some cases, but in this case, with this structure, it could scale to huge documents which is not good either. And also it makes the queries and restrictions you want much harder to achieve. And you won't notice any difference in speed until we're talking about millions of documents anyway.

Comment: @JonathanNielsen can you just explain how these "compound unique indexes" works  and how should I implement according to my requirement.

Comment: You can set one property, like post title to be unique, mongodb will throw an error if you try to insert 2 documents with the same title. Compound indexes is a unique combination. In this case, mongodb will not throw an error if the same user write multiple reviews, nor will it throw an error if there is multiple reviews for the same location. But if you try to insert 2 documents or more with the same user for the same location it will raise an error, which is exactly what you want. Add this before the export  `reviewSchema.index({ user: 1, location: 1 }, { unique: true });`

Comment: @JonathanNielsen How to achieve many to many relationship in case of Post and location and user using schema ? can you suggest me the all schemas

Comment: I'm sorry, but I will not write you all the schemas. It's quite a lot of work and you'll learn much more if you try it yourself, I've given you the resources for many-to-many relationships, google arond and check the docuemntation for mongoose virtuals.

Comment: @JonathanNielsen [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61559376/in-which-mongoose-schema-i-should-store-the-reference-id) these are my schemas please have a look and give some suggestions if any